# ASP.NET MVC: Which JavaScript toolkit works best?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just wondering which JavaScript library/toolkit works the best with ASP.NET MVC? Is it just a question of what the individual programmer prefers or is there actually some benefits with some of the toolkits over the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) works fantastically. See:

- [What advantages does jQuery have
  over other JavaScript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045/what-advantages-does-jquery-have-over-other-javascript-librarie)
- [Microsoft AJAX client library vs
  jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609683/microsoft-ajax-client-library-vs-jquery)
- [Why is jQuery so widely adopted
  versus other Javascript
  frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990077/why-is-jquery-so-widely-adopted-versus-other-javascript-frameworks)
- [Integrating jQuery into an existing
  ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148202/integrating-jquery-into-an-existing-asp-net-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

The toolkits that are included with the standard project within MVC are great. Probably [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is the preferred as it does give you an lot of control over the output (which is one of the selling points of MVC in the first place. [JQueryUI](http://ui.jquery.com/) gives some added bonuses on top of that as well.

Both JQuery and JQuery UI perform different tasks within the software develpment process. JQuery allows you to perform all of your custom requirements and scenarios. The UI is basically way of plugging in common functionality (i.e. a calendar date picker, etc). There is a little bit of crossover in places, but that's basically it.

You may find MS Ajax useful at times - but i'd just consider the frameworks on a problem-by-problem basis. Personally I prefer to 'default to JQuery' unless there is a compelling reason to re-evaluate what to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo what's been said, jQuery works well, but I would suggest looking at the other options just to be certain that in your specific case there isn't something out there that's more appropriate.

Check out the information here. It's a good starting point with additional links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks